# How to see and proof that the hyperbola as a constant difference of distances holds for $\frac{1}{x}$?

Tags: geometry, algebra-precalculus, intuition, conic-sections, plane-curves

I understand that a [hyperbola](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola#Difference_of_distances_to_foci) can be defined as the locus of all points on a plane such that the absolute value of the difference between the distance to the foci is $2a$, which is the distance between the two vertices (for clarification see also this example from [wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/97/Hyperbola_properties.svg)).

How can I intuitively see and easily proof that this holds for $y=\frac{1}{x}$?

Comment: Please try to clarify your notion of distance here, the question as such is unclear.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/544012/why-are-two-definitions-of-ellipses-equivalent

Comment: @AlexR: What exactly is unclear to you? The first part gives a definition of the hyperbola (see also link to wikipedia which is included), the second part asks the question how to prove that this def. holds for 1/x.

Comment: @vonjd I have read the original formulation; I did not understand your final remark here, since it made no sense to me gramatically.

Comment: @AlexR: I am afraid I still don't understand: What part doesn't make sense gramatically?!?

Comment: ", the distance between the two vertices". Vertices should say foci and maybe a little "which is" helps separate it from the rest; I read it as something like $|d(x,f_1) - f(x,f_2)| = 2a d(f_1, f_2)$

Comment: @AlexR: I edited the question - is it clearer now?

Comment: May have  a look into Article $\#393$ of The elements of coordinate geometry (1895) by Loney (https://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone)

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44391/foci-of-a-general-conic-equation

Comment: @vonjd Yes, it is. Thanks :)